# Designing Forms for html email

Tags: css, forms, css-selectors, html-email

I have two buttons side by side in an ***html email***
below the two buttons, there's an input field
and below the input field, there's a submit button

I want the two buttons to behave as toggles
and the input field would take optional inputs from the recipient.
so that when the submit button is clicked i send the selected state (i.e, yes, if first button is selected, and a no if the other is selected or clicked)

I also intend to show the currently selected choice by changing the background of the selected button when it is clicked or hovered.

The problem is, i tried using

```
#button:hover
```

but the color change doesn't persist and on submit, i don't know how to get which button is selected.

I have also tried wrapping the button in an a-tag, and using

```
a:visited table #button
```

but the change is permanent, even after refresh, once it has been clicked.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

### EDIT:

#### Here's the code for the button

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td id="frown" align="center" width="270" height="40" bgcolor="#D83934" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
            <a style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
                <img src="frowny.png">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Here's the css I've tried

```
a:visited table #frown {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

But once clicked and the background changes, i have no way of returning to the original colour when the other button if clicked.

Comment: do you have any sample code to show us?

Comment: i just added some samples

Answer (score 1):

Forms are **not** possible in html emails, mail clients sees forms as phishing attempts. 
So you need to link to a landingpage with a form on.

And for some email cliens strips the CSS in the top(gmail), so all CSS needs to be inline.